# Don't understand double list lookups

Tags: python, list

I can't figure out the output of this code:

```
lst = [3,1,4,-2]
print(lst[lst[-1]])

    # output 4
```

**or**

```
lst = [3,1,4,-2]
print(lst[lst[3]])

    # output 4
```

Comment: Your examples are wrong. The output for both would be -2, as indices of -4 and 0 refer to the same element. But what exactly has confused you about that code?

Comment: I don't agree with the close votes on this - the question's clear to me. The OP doesn't understand why the code has the output that it does.

Comment: If you understand single list lookup you can decompose double lookup to two singles)

Comment: I edit the examples in the post,  that's what I actually meant, why -1 output's -4 ?

Comment: Anyway, I got it know, thanks to some answers

Answer (score 1):

```
lst[0] = 3
lst[lst[0]] = lst[3] = -2

lst[-4] = 3
lst[lst[-4]] = lst[3] = -2
```

Comment: You should include some explanation so that the OP can understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
list=[3,1,4,-2]
print(list[list[0]])
-2

Explanation:
list[0] = 3
substitute this value in list[list[0]] which makes it list[3]
finally print(list[3]) whose output will be -2



list=[3,1,4,-2]
print(list[list[-4]])
-2

Explanation:
list[-4] is 3
substitute this value in list[list[-4]] which makes it list[3]
finally print(list[3]) whose output will be -2
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way: `lst[-4]` and `lst[0]` just return numbers (-2 and 3, respectively).

Thus,

```
lst = [3,1,4,-2]
print(lst[lst[0]])
```

is no different than

```
lst = [3,1,4,-2]
print(lst[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the second example,

```
lst = [3,1,4,-2] 
print(lst[lst[-4]])
```

`lst[-4]` returns `3`, the index value of `-1` gives the last element, and `-2` gives the second last element of an array and likewise, `-4` returns the 4th last element.

Since `lst[-4]` returns `3` we have `print(lst[3])` which returns third indexed element of the array, which is `-2`, considering 0 being first element.

In the first example, it goes like above where final output should be `-2`

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `index` operator `[]` to access an item in a list. Index starts from 0. So, a list having 5 elements will have an index from 0 to 4. Trying to access an element other that this will raise an `IndexError`.

Python also allows negative indexing for its sequences. The `index` of -1 refers to the last item, -2 to the second last item and so on.

From your example

```
lst = [3, 1, 4, -2]
       0  1  2   3  # +ve index
      -4 -3 -2  -1  # -ve index

>>> print(lst[lst[0]])  # lst[0] is 3 ==> lst[3] is -2
-2
>>> print(lst[lst[-4]])  # lst[-4] is 3 ==> lst[3] is -2
-2
```